# Passport not stamped on arrival at Melbourne Airport

Tags: indian-citizens, passport-stamps, australian-residents

I have an Indian passport and, although I didn't use the smart gates for immigration, my passport wasn't stamped when I arrived at Melbourne Airport.

Is this a cause for concern or should I contact the immigration department to get the passport stamped?

Comment: Immigrating back to Parent country (still quite manual process of immi check is done) , they keep asking questions "why no stamp is there"

Comment: Indian Passport. Yes somewhat , last time i was held for over half hour (when everything was clean) and had to explain travel history.

Comment: @pnuts I guess it's because without any stamps, they may suspect you hold another citizenship, which is not allowed for Indians

Comment: @pnuts when i was on temporary visa my passport was stamped on Arrival in 2014 , but not this time around in 2017.

Comment: Maybe next time you should say "may I have a stamp, please?" If they don't give you a stamp, ask why, and if they have an explanation, ask if you can get it in writing. Maybe they have a brochure explaining their procedures. More likely, they'll just stamp your passport for you.

Comment: For now can i visit the airport and ask the customs & immi people to do it for me ?

Answer (score 2):

All Australian visa, arrival and departure records are electronic, so **passports are generally not stamped on arrival**. (They are still often stamped on departure, even for Australian citizens, unless you use the automated gates. I'm not sure why.)

If you need proof of having been in Australia on certain dates, you can either request a stamp.on entry (and not use an automated gate, although this is not available to Indian citizens anyway), or request a Record of International Movements: http://japan.embassy.gov.au/tkyo/intlmovement.html

Note that for the latter, the application process is bureaucratic (certified copies etc) and processing time is several weeks, so it's not going to helpful if you have a short trip and need.to.prove it.immediately afterwards.

I'm reasonably sure that going back to the airport after arrival and requesting a stamp is not going to work, but let us know what happened if you do try it...